# Finding the min (or max) of a class in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im working on a large dataset (with pandas in python) and I have a dataframe similar structured to the following:

```
   class   value
0    1       6
1    1       4
2    1       5
3    5       6
4    5       2
...
n   225      3
```

The classes grow through the dataframe continuously, however; missing some values as shown in the example. I was wondering how I can get simple stats like min, or max from each class and assign it to a new feature.

```
     class   value   min   
0      1       6      4
1      1       4      4
2      1       5      4
3      5       6      2
4      5       2      2
...   
n     225      3      3
```

The only solution I can come up with is with a time consuming loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `transform`

```
df['min']=df.groupby('class')['value'].transform('min')
df
Out[497]: 
   class  value  min
0      1      6    4
1      1      4    4
2      1      5    4
3      5      6    2
4      5      2    2
```